# Trouble installing gulp

Tags: npm, gulp

Hi I am trying to install gulp and its not working and just returns this message.

```
$ npm install gulp --save-dev


npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                            to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                            to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail o                           n node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible                           . Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.


npm WARN abc@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN abc@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Answer (score 1):

These are just Warnings that can be ignored. To check if the module was properly installed, Try the following command to check the version installed:

```
npm list | grep gulp
```

It will list the version that previous command installed. If you don't get any version, then check version of npm are you using. Kindly update the version of npm and try again. It looks like that your npm version is outdated.

```
npm install -g npm
```